# Who Survived In The Supernatural Series Finale and who not?

Tags: supernatural

I hope the question is broad enough not to be considered a spoiler. Obviously the concrete question is a huge spoiler:

> After Jack "unsnapped" it seems that all people are brought back. But in the last episode we see Sam and Dean continuing their life completely alone. No short "reunitied" shot with Sam and Eileen (who he lost shortly before and if she was brought back surely one of the first things Sam would do is go and meet her). No shots with Donna, Jody or the apocalypse people. No party with the friends at the bunker. Also at Deans funeral, Sam is alone. No other friends are present, giving Dean a Good bye. We see Sam having a son but the mother is not shown or shown blured. We do not see if it is Eileen. So what happens to all the people? Are Donna, Jody, Garth brought back? If yes, why didn't they show up at least at Deans funeral? If not, why not? What about Eileen? If she was brought back, why wasn't the first thing Sam does to visit her (or why was it done offscreen)? What about the apocalypse people? Why are Sam and Dean shown continuing their life all alone until Deans death?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'survived'. Potentially everyone, even God, in some realm.